# Инициализация firebase в main.js vue. Error 'app' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars

Tags: vue.js, firebase, auth, vue3, vue-cli

Пытаюсь инициализировать firebase для регистрации/авторизации. Ошибка
Error  'app' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
Помогите разобраться в чем проблема

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { firebaseConfig } from './firebaseConfig';

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig); // Инициализация Firebase

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

Comment: Может быть, ```import { initializeApp } from './firebase/app';```?